# How do I access elements in this dataset using objc?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm struggling with this dataset:

`stopsArray: (
        (
                {
            DistanceFromStart = 0;
            Ordinal = 1;
            Stop =             {
                Lat = "38.90282440185547";
                Lon = "-77.03208160400391";
                OrgAbbr = "<null>";
                OrgId = DcCi;
                StopCode = 1001259;
                StopId = "DcCi_1445_7727";
                StopName = "NW 14TH ST & NW K ST";
            };
        },
                {
            DistanceFromStart = "0.443314063224555";
            Ordinal = 2;
            Stop =             {
                Lat = "38.90834426879883";
                Lon = "-77.03208923339844";
                OrgAbbr = "<null>";
                OrgId = DcCi;
                StopCode = 1001393;
                StopId = "DcCi_1445_7808";
                StopName = "NW 14TH ST & NW RHODE ISLAND AV";
            };
        },
                {
            DistanceFromStart = "1.050716048463951";
            Ordinal = 3;
            Stop =             {
                Lat = "38.91703033447266";
                Lon = "-77.03196716308594";
                OrgAbbr = "<null>";
                OrgId = DcCi;
                StopCode = 17348;
                StopId = "DcCi_1445_6674";
                StopName = "NW 14TH ST & NW U ST";
            };
        },`

1. I'm not sure if this is an array, a dictionary, or a combination. How do I tell the difference?
2. How would I pull out the "Ordinal" field, as well as elements in the "Stop" dataset?

To get the `stopsArray` data, I used this line:

`stopsArray = [variantArray valueForKey:@"Stops"];`

I've tried to pull the first Ordinal field (i.e. 1) with this:

`NSMutableArray *array = stopsArray[0];
    NSString *string = [array valueForKey:@"Ordinal"];
    NSLog(@"string: %@", string);`

But that results in:

`string: (
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7
)`

Any ideas to stop my hair coming out would be most welcome.

I'll keep at it meanwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, its an array of objects of type dictionary.

Secondly, the data doesn't seem to be properly formatted.

Its like an array with a single object of type dictionary, but that single object contains all the different dictionary values.

hence your result of

```
string: (
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7
)
```

What seems to me the problem is the second open bracket

```
stopsArray: (
        (
             {
```

Try doing this...

```
NSMutableArray *array = stopsArray[0];
NSMutableArray *actualDataArray = array[0];
```

and then

```
NSString *string = [actualDataArray[INDEX_OF_DIC_OBJECT] valueForKey:@"Ordinal"];
    NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
```

Lemme know if it works.

**Updated Solution**
What eventually worked for  David DelMonte.

```
NSString *string = [[[stopsArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Ordinal"];
```

Comment: You got me thinking. I tried this: `NSString *string = [[[stopsArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Ordinal"];` and it works. Too soon to say it's solved..